# Prevent debuggers to see variable value

Tags: java, security, reflection, permissions, securitymanager

Is there a way that I can configure properties of my JPA(I am using hibernate as implementation) entity such that no one can see its value while debugging?

The property is transient and I don't want anyone to see it while debugging due to security reasons. The jar/war of my application will be used by third party.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ - what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: yes, make sure they don't get your code, so they won't be able to debug it.
Debugging is pointless unless you can actually check what's going on 'under the hood', that's what debugging is all about. you can always encode it, so that it becomes 'unreadable', I guess.

Comment: If someone can attach a debugger to your Java program, you should assume they can see everything in it. You should probably assume, for instance, that even if they couldn't see the JPA field, they could see the local var with its value whenever it's set or used.

Comment: @Stultuske Code can be decompiled. Intellij does it by default if you don't have the source code (I don't know about other IDEs). It'll lack comments, and local variable names are gone, but it's generally not much harder to follow than if you did have the source. Certainly not hard enough to be considered even remotely secure.

Comment: @yshavit so don't distribute the code, jar, ear ...
run it on your own (web)server and only distribute a client that connects to it. If it is distributed, you should be aware that when push comes to shove: 'anything goes'

Comment: @stultuske but then they can't debug it, either. The question was specifically about hiding information in a debugging session. "Yes, but only if they can't attach a debugger" in that context is "no." :-) To the OP: I'm nearly sure the answer is no, but I can't find anything in a quick search that explicitly stated that.

Comment: @yshavit the whole point of debugging is to make sure the one doing it can check the values during the flow, so he can find any issues. Either you want someone to be able to debug, or you want that person not to be able to see the values, can't have it both, though :)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. :) The OP seems to want the best of both worlds: most values are accessible, but certain ones aren't. It's a reasonable idea, though as I said, I don't believe it's possible in Java.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. it has more to do with java security. I am going through Reflection and Java SecurityManager to see the possibility of this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're running your program on an Oracle JVM, and allowing people to attach to that JVM via a debugger -- no, you can't hide certain fields.

The interface that the debuggers will use to talk to the Java process is [JDI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/index.html) <sup>1</sup>, and it gives pretty much all of the information that the JVM has about your code. Specifically:

- If a person has an [ObjectReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ObjectReference.html) to the object that contains your sensitive data, they can get its ReferenceType.
- They can call [`ReferenceType::allFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ReferenceType.html#allFields--) to list *all* of the fields, including transient ones, in the class:

  > All declared and inherited fields are included, regardless of whether they are hidden or multiply inherited.
- Back on the ObjectReference, they can call [`ObjectReference::getValue(Field)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ObjectReference.html#getValue-com.sun.jdi.Field-) to get the field's value. Note that the documentation doesn't say anything about an IllegalAccessException, or anything like that.

Even if you could lock down certain fields, it wouldn't do you much good; the debugger would be able to see the value when it's in a local variable (either when you read the field, or when you're about to write to it). What you really want is to lock down certain *values*, not fields. And that's also not in the JDI.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually [JDWP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/architecture.html#interfaces) under the hood, but JDI is built on top of that and easier to discuss here.